# My 2010 Jaguar XK will very occasionally struggle to accelerate only when starting from low speed

Tags: starting, acceleration, throttle, shaking, jaguar

new to the forum! My 2010 Jaguar XK will very occasionally struggle to accelerate when I am running it at low speeds of about 10-15 mph. When I try to go above 10-15 mph, the car will create a lot of noise but won't move any faster. I would be forced to pull-over and restart the engine, after which the problem will go away for days or weeks at a time. This problem has occurred 4 times over the past 6 months. The typical situation when this problem occurs is after I had just started the car. I believe there was one time where the problem had occurred after sitting at a long red light.

There are no acceleration issues once I am driving above about 15 mph. I am able to drive normally for long periods, and frequently on the highways for multiple hours at above 60 mph.

Asked my local independent Jaguar mechanic, and he said when this problem occurs so infrequently, it's nearly impossible to track down. So now I'm at a loss for what to do, scared it might happen more frequently down the road. I read cleaning the throttle body or MAF might help, but also read that cleaning the throttle body on a Jaguar XK is not recommended due to some kind of special coating placed by the manufacturer?

Comment: Join this forum : www.jaguarforum.com ,they are all Jag owners / drivers or work on them and are really helpful - Disclaimer: I have a Jag and am a member!! They have seen all the issues...

Comment: Please do, you will be welcomed.

Comment: Is it an auto? If so I'd suspect something gearbox related. Particularly with the mention of rising noise but no accompanying acceleration. Could it be that it's not shifting up?